# DAX to convert to Minutes and Seconds

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following DAX:

```
(sum(usage[session_duration])/100)/sum(usage[engaged_sessions])
```

The problem I have is it returns depending on the filters 2.49, when it should be returning 4.09. 4 for the number of minutes, and 9 for the seconds.

I wrote the following:

```
Var FirstTotal = (sum(usage[session_duration])/100)/sum(usage[engaged_sessions])
Var SecondTotal = FirstTotal*100
Var ThirdTotal = SecondTotal/60
VAR WholeNumberThirdTotal = INT(ThirdTotal)
Var FirstDot = FIND(".",ThirdTotal,1,0)
Var FourthTotal = MID(ThirdTotal, FirstDot, 2)
Var FifthTotal = FourthTotal*60

RETURN WholeNumberThirdTotal & "." & FifthTotal
```

and this seems to return the correct results. The problem I have with the above though is that I can't use it within a graph with a Date field. It only works within a Card.

Anyone know how I can improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me the following returns a value in units of seconds:

```
SUM ( usage[session_duration] ) / SUM ( usage[engaged_sessions] )
```

I.e., without the `/100` you have 249s, which is the same as 4m + 9s.

You can add formatting to this to get the display you're after:

```
VAR Sec = SUM ( usage[session_duration] ) / SUM ( usage[engaged_sessions] )
RETURN
    FORMAT ( INT ( Sec / 60 ), "0" ) & "." & FORMAT ( MOD ( Sec, 60 ), "00" )
```

As you point out, this is a text value so it can't be used as a numerical value in chart visuals. You *can* convert 249 into the decimal value 4.09 just as easily:

```
VAR Sec = SUM ( usage[session_duration] ) / SUM ( usage[engaged_sessions] )
RETURN
    INT ( Sec / 60 ) + MOD ( Sec, 60 ) / 100
```

If you use this in a bar chart, the height of the bars will be proportional to 4.09 minutes (i.e. 4m + 5.4s) rather than 4m + 9s (4.15 m).

Since Power BI doesn't have a duration type available for measures, if you're using a single measure, you must either sacrifice some accuracy in charting or not show the labels on the chart in the format you prefer. If you don't need to show labels on your graph, you can just use `Sec / 60` for the graph and the formatted version wherever the numbers are displayed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! Appreciate it greatly. If I go with an example of VAR SEC = 78900 / 335 = 235.52. How does that finish up at 3.56? I don't quite understand the RETURN formula for getting that result.

Comment: INT(235.52/60) + MOD(235.52,60)/100 = INT(3.925)) + 55.52/100 = 3 + 0.5552 = 3.56 to two decimal places.